# Как ускорить работу алгоритма поиска наибольшего значения массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, поиск

На данный момент я изучаю простейшие алгоритмы поиска и указатели, в связи с чем у меня возник вопрос:

Как можно ускорить данный алгоритм поиска наибольшего значения в элементах массива?

```
int array[]{ 1,4,6,2};

    int max = 0;
    
    for (auto i : array)
    {
        if (i > max) max = i;
    }
    
std::cout << max;
```

1. У меня были мысли преобразовать объявляемый элемент (i) в указатель, чтобы принимать адрес ячейки массива, но в цикле for-each, видимо, это невозможно.
2. Также была идея преобразовать (int max) в указатель, чтобы хранить адрес объявляемого элемента (i), но чтобы произвести первое сравнение max и i, max должен указывать на какое-то значение.

Понимаю, что скорее всего есть готовое решение в STL бибилиотеке, однако моя дотошность не дает покоя.
Есть ли смысл вообще думать на эту тему?

Comment: Запустить, например восемь потоков параллельно на разные участки памяти. А потом выбрать из восьми самый большой.

Comment: @Павел-Ериков я правильно понимаю:
в вашем примере объявляемый элемент при каждой итерации цикла создается заново, что и позволяет ему ссылаться на новый элемент массива?

Comment: @AlexGlebe до многопоточности еще не дошел, но спасибо:)

Comment: На эту тему есть смысл думать, чтобы не написать плохой алгоритм.  Что бы вы не писали, придется рассматривать все элементы и придется сравнивать или явно или под "капотом". Так что для данного  случая лучше не напишете. Для встроенных типов ссылка только ухудшит. Подсказка от  Павел Ериков   не верна

Comment: @Павел-Ериков я понимаю, что в таком случае i работает с ссылкой. 
Но ведь, ссылочный тип может ссылаться лишь на один обьект и ссылку нельзя изменить в будущем, но в случае с циклом for-each он будет при каждой итерации получать адрес следующего элемента массива. 
А как это происходит "под копотом"? 
Область существования i сохраняется лишь на момент одной интерации? Именно это позволяет i принимать последующие элемента массива?

Comment: @Павел Ериков, чтобы долго не отвечать, поищите, должны быть ответы на эту тему, и даже в этом сайте по моему был такой вопрос.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков а какой в этом смысл? Менять элемент не нужно, да и это ничего не ускорит, возможно даже наоборот: int, обычно, занимает 4 байта, а ссылка - 8. Таким образом не понятно зачем вы это советуете?

Comment: @ReturnNullprt поиск максимума - это задача которая решается за O(n). можно пытаться ускорить, пытаясь "перехитрить компилятор", но в большинстве случаев это только ухудшит скорость. Одно дело, если в массиве большие объекты (размером десятки байт) - там указатели/ссылки/итераторы помогут (просто не копировать без причины), но для примитивных типов - нет. Но если исполльзовать специальные инструкции процессора, к примеру _mm512_max_epi32, то можно по 16 элементов за один раз сравнивать и получить прирост.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch размер указателя 8, а ссылки 4 [тест](https://onlinegdb.com/MILkkQinp)

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за развернутый ответ! 
Запомню, как раз прохожу понятие времени выполнения алгоритма.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Ваш тест не верный, sizeof ссылки выдаст размер типа

Comment: @SelfishCrawler а теперь попробуйте для `double`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков не знаю где вы там такое нашли, но я там не нашел, чтобы писали что-то вроде "без ссылки не рекомендуется"

Comment: @SelfishCrawler ваш тест неверный: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof - sizeof от ссылки возвращает размер типа на который указывает ссылка

Comment: есть просто ряд людей, которые, что бы случайно не написать "неэффективный код", всегда пишут единообразно. К примеру, всегда добавляют `const&` к переменным (даже если там char) или пишут `++i` в цикле всегда (вот это такой холиварный вопрос, что я даже не буду отвечать на критику этого)

Comment: По-моему, быстрее, чем `int max = array[0]; for(int i = 1; i < size(array); ++i) if (max < array[i]) max = array[i];` ничего не сделать. Разве что распараллеливать или векторизовать - но это сработает только на реально больших массивах.

Comment: Чтобы проверить размер напишите так: `#pragma pack(1) struct alpha{int &val;} ... std::cout << sizeof(alpha) << std::endl;`

Comment: главное, что бы массив не был пустой, @Harry

Comment: Второй метод ускорение - использование SSE MMX (конечно это ассемблер). Третий метод ускорение - приколы разрядности. Например если для 8-битных значений применять 32-битные операции, то теоретически возможно добится ускорения. На практике - не уверен что даст ускорение.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я не знаю откуда вы эту фразу выдернули, я не могу ее прокоментировать - покажите откуда вы ее взяли

Comment: 4-тый метод ускорения - отказаться от цикла и найти вложеными if, но годится только для массива малой размерности который не меняет свой размер, т.е. 4 элемента не больше не меньше.

Comment: @nick_n_a 5-ый метод - искать максимум в отсортированном массиве

Comment: @SelfishCrawler и какое ускорение сдесь будет? Сортировка массива - более затратная операция, нежели поиск значения в неотсортированном массиве. Таким образом если вам нужно всего одна операция поиска - это не имеет никакого смысла и будет иметь обратный эффект

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch понятно что сортировка куда более затратная операция, это был сарказм.

Comment: 4. Есть макрос max_что-то, для массив постоянного размера в кодеках, анализаторах применяют макрос. Для 4 он будет быстрее цикла. `#define MAX2X(a,b) ((a>b)?a:b)` тогда `x= MAX2X( MAX2X(a[0],a[1]), MAX2X(a[2],a[3]))` Даст ответ быстрее чем цикл. В зависимости от условий задачи, в часных случаях можно применить "хитрость", если она применима конечно. Конечно если у вас массив переменного размера - то применить такое нельзя.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков да хоспати, конечно это тяжело заметить, когда вы не в силах даже google translate освоить! `Not preferred` переводится как "не предпочтительный"! А не "не рекомендуется". И ключевое слово (что не рекумендуется) это "as specific value" - тобишь вместо `auto` указан кокретный тип `int`. Об этом же говориться и статье: Обратите внимание, что auto ключевое слово является предпочтительным в for-range-declaration части инструкции

Comment: @nick_n_a можно ли развить эту идею и применять макрос в цикле, например за один проход находить максимум из сета трех элементов и проскакивать их счетчиком? Подойдет например для массивов с числом элементов кратных 3. Будет ли ускорение в таком случае?

Comment: @nick_n_a, думаю, в данном случаи, для современных компиляторов все эти хитрости не нужны.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вас не смущает сочетание "почти всегда"? Нет? Я просто приведу то что вы сами написали в начале: я нашел на microsoft что вообще без ссылки не рекумендуется писать. "Почти всегда нежелательна" и "вообще не рекомендуется" - разве имеют тот же смысл?

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Можно сделать template с условными макросами - тогда до определённого элементов числа можно предопределить поиск. А компилятор на каждый чих сгенерирует код. Для массивов с постоянным числом элементов - подойдёт. Для переменных - нет

Comment: Увидел `max = 0`  - никогда так не делайте при поиске max. Правильно писать или `max=array[0]` или в крайнем случае  `max=-infinity` но infinity как правило не используют. Или в один прекрасный день - получите баг или незачёт

Comment: @nick_n_a да,вы правы, пришел к этому, когда решил исползовать поиск среди элементов с отрицательными значениями.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую собрать в едино все споры из комментариев.

Касательно ускорения - смысл ускорения - это использовать какие-то необычные принципы, которые могут дать результат за меньшее к-во тактов процессора. Ниже поясню что используется для ускорения и зачем.

1. Указание `auto` даёт свободу компилятору, и он сможет делать с переменной что захочет, например задействовать регистр процессора (они самые быстрые), а не создавать её в стеке. Это и есть ускорение. Так же это "сигнал" оптимизатору, который возможно применит тут оптимизацию которую он умеет делать. Возможно указание `register` вместо `auto` даст тот же результат, несколько лет назад отдельные источники рекомендовали `register`.
2. Использование SSE MMX. Есть определенный набор команд, который позволяет, например сравнивать одновременно 4 пары чисел за одну инструкцию. При колличестве данных думаю от 1000 штук, это даст эффект. Писать нужно на ассемблере, и такой набор команд должен быть на процессорах у того - кто будет использовать программу. Т.е. или intel/amd или свежий intel/amd, не ARMv7 и т п.
3. Использование встроеных в ЦП операций большей разрядности над данными меньшей разрядности. Например 32-битных или 64-битных операций над 8-битными числами.
   Если массив у вас 8-битный беззнаковый, то применив тест допустим  `*((int*)(a + i)) & 0xF0F0F0F0`  (что равно `*((int*)&a[i]) & 0xF0F0F0F0`) вы можете проверить, содержит ли двойное слово байты больше чем 15 (0xFF-0xF0 = 0xF = 15) или не содержит. Если не содержит - то условно не делать поиск внутри этих 4-х байт раздельно сэкономив 3-ри инструкции сравнения, иначе итого 1+4=5 инструкций (вместо 4) + накладные расходы. При определённых условиях это может дать небольшой прирост производительности. Возможно можно ещё придумать похожую "хитрость" игры с битами.
4. Отказ от цикла улучшает производительность. Если к-во елементов в цикле внутри алгоритма - константа и оно малое, где-то до 20 или до 100 элементов (я так думаю, возможно и до 1000) - то можно составить древесную условную структуру, для поиска максимума без цикла, что даст ускорение. В этом поможет тернарный оператор.

   ```
   #define MAX2X(a,b) ((a>b)?a:b)
   // тогда
   max = MAX2X(a[0],a[1]); // для  двух
   max = MAX2X(MAX2X(a[0],a[1]), a[2]); // для трёх
   max = MAX2X(MAX2X(a[0],a[1]), MAX2X(a[2],a[3])); // для чётырёх
   ```

Универсальный поиск можно сделать через template. В template-аргументы можно подставлять константы.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T FindMax(T (&a)[N])
{
  switch (N) {            
      case 2: return MAX2X(a[0],a[1]);
      case 3: // .....
      // и так далее
      default:
         // assert-ошибка
         ;
      }
}
```

Учтите что такое ускорение приводит к разрастанию кода. До определённого момента ускорение будет расти, но после критического значения будет падать.

Может ли оптимизатор сам сгенерироваь такое из примера который в вопросе - сомневаюсь.

5. Если уже зараннее извесно что массив осортирован - то максимум - крайний элемент. (Если по-возрастанию - то последний элемент).
6. Если данных более 10000 то распараленый поиск (т.е. ответ ищёт несколько ядер  процессора - посредством threads) - даёт результат лучше чем линейный.
7. Из пожеланий, отдельные методы поиска можно применить используя библиотечную [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Некоторые из этих методов можно смешивать вместе, что даст ещё больше вариантов найти максимум, некоторые из смешений могут быть эффективны.

Из ошибок. `max=0` - так при поиске максисмума не принято делать. Конкретно в даном случае это сработает, но в будущем это может привести к багам, незачёту, да и каждый кто увидет такой "почерк" скажет что вы непрофессионал в плохом смысле слова.

UDP *Также была идея преобразовать (int max) в указатель* Если max сделать указателем, то для проверки указатель прийдётся привести к неуказателю, а это дополнительная операция. Поэтому вместо четырёх сревнений с регистром будет операция памяти получения значения по-указателю, а потом сравнение из памяти - итого 8 (минимум) операций с памятью вместо 4. Поэтому вместо ускорения вы получите наоборот - замедление, раза в 1,5-2. Если L0 кеш имеет скорость регистров (не уверен) то есть шанс получить ту же скорость.

P.S. Используйте обычный линейный цикл, или библиотечную функцию. А ускорение - ускорение есть смысл делать только если вы анализируете очень большие обьёмы данных, там пишите компрессор/декомпрессор, или анализ больших массивов данных, или что-то где скорость имеет важное значение.

Comment: Поиск _максимума_ в _отсортированном_ массиве двоичным поиском?..

Comment: Я понял))))))))

Comment: Ещё есть стандартный [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), который, _теоретически_, должен быть максимально оптимизирован, и ему можно передавать execution policy, чтобы он ещё и параллельно выполнялся.

Comment: А еще можно заменить `*((int*)&a[i]) & 0xF0F0F0F0` на `*((int*)(a + i)) & 0xF0F0F0F0`. Я так понимаю, оператор `[]` получает указатель на требуемый элемент посредством арифметики на указателях, а потом его разыменовывает, а потом вы снова получаете указатель. Можно самому использовать такую же операцию, но остановиться на получении указателя. Да, прироста почти не даст, но раз уж занимаемся оптимизацией поиска максимума, то почем бы и нет :)

Comment: @Стас, думаю, что замена `&a[i]` на `(a + i)` вообще никакого прироста не даст. Что-то вы совсем плохого мнения о компиляторах :)

Comment: @Стас часть программистов любят первую форму записи, часть - вторую форму записи, не всем кто любит первую понятна вторая и наоборот. Они равнозначны, потому что в обеих случаях берётся адрес элемента вначале. Я предпочитаю через `a[i]`. Но оставлю обе формы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать :)